# ASP.NET Core Web API pipeline Does Not Work As expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API using C#.

When I changed `app.Run();` in `program.cs` file to this:

```
app.Run(async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("I'm upgrading!\nTRY AGAIN LATER");
});
```

The application does not show me the message and does not open either!
Does anybody know the reason?

I tried to change the pipeline but it didn't work.

My `program.cs` file is now like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run(async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("I'm upgrading!\nTRY AGAIN LATER");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// ...

app.Run(async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("I'm upgrading!\nTRY AGAIN LATER");
});

app.Run();
```